# Xcode: Architectures settings for a universal\iOS4 app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, armv7, armv6

I was wondering what my project settings should be in case I have a universal app that I am now updating to 4.0.

The Base SDK is iPhone Device 4.0
iPhone OS Deployment Target is iPhone OS 3.0

What should I enter in the Architectures, Build Active Architecture Only checkbox and the Valis Architectures for the different configurations (debug, release)?

Also, since some of my apps are not universal but will support 4.0 as base and 3.0 as deployment, will it make any difference is the architectures settings?

Thanks

Roi

Comment: By universal, I take that you want to be able to deploy to both iOS 3.x and 4.0, right?

Comment: By Universal I mean it will run on both iPad and iPhone

Comment: If iPad, base SDK and deployment target are both 3.2.  Also, it's Xcode,not xCode.

Comment: Since I am building an application that is both Universal and supports iOS4 I read that it is advised to set the Base SDK as iPhone Device 4.0 and the iPhone OS Deployment Target as iPhone OS 3.0.
What you are suggesting to set both on 3.2 simply won't work for me.

Comment: You should be able to use the default values for all architecture settings. If they have been modified, click them and press delete to return them to default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base SDK should be set to the most recent version of the SDK (ie: 4.2) this is what you build against and ensures that your app works properly on new OS's. Xcode now has a 'Latest iOS' selection which I recommend.

Deployment Target is the minimum version you want your app to be able to be installed on. This is mostly dictated by the features you want to use. If you want features introduced in iOS 4, you need to set the deployment target to 4.0.

also, be careful that these are set identically for all configurations and don't vary between development and release.